# Why is my program so slow in querying my Access database outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: microsoft-access, visual-studio

Recently I started having a problem with my program taking considerably longer to perform a basic Access database query when the exe was run on its own.

When my program is run from within Visual Studio 2013, the results are almost instant, but the same query takes up to 10 seconds when the exe is run on its own.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot (about 4 days) of trial and error research it turned out to be the Application Verifier that slowed things down so much.  I corrected the problem as follows:

Open Registry editor and back up registry (just in case)

Browse Registry as follows:

--> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

--> Software

--> Microsoft

--> Windows NT

--> CurrentVersion

--> Image File Execution Options

Then I deleted the Key containg my program's name.

From there my problem was solved.  I hope this helps someone.